# Trying to debounce search function calls results in no event passed to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am working with a library named [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) using its `debounce()` function to sort of limit api calls for search suggestions i.e. instead of calling api every time user changes a field I debounce it and wait 300ms from when they finish typing:

it looks like this in my component:

```
class myComponent extends Component {

  //Handle listing search
  searchListing(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  //Render
  render() {
    const listingSearch = _.debounce( () => { this.searchListing() }, 300  );

    return (
        <TextInput onChange={listingSearch}/>

    );
  }
}
```

it works and calls the function however I get an error saying: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

So I tried passing an event like so:

```
const listingSearch = _.debounce( (event) => { this.searchListing(event) }, 300  );
```

Now error says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` after inspecting this event I'm passing, I can see that it has empty target, so is not working correctly.

Comment: I've created example based on you code - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/31603/ - and it works fine when pass `event` as argument. Could you post code for `TextInput`?

Comment: have you seen example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to include `event.persist();` inside my onChange handler function.

So:

```
  searchListing(event) {
    event.persist();
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```